# How do I search through a structure and display certain info after it has been entered by the user?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, structure

For my assignment I am to create a structure that allows the user to enter student info (ID, DOB, & Phone number). I have no problem doing this that is quite simple. Now I need to search through that enter info using the student ID to display that students corresponding DOB and phone number, this is the problem that I am having trouble working with. If you see any other problems with my program please let me know what is wrong and why I should change so I can learn from my mistakes.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct infoStruct 
{
    int studentID;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int phone;
    int end;
};

int main (void)
{
int students = 0;   
int infoArray [students];
struct infoStruct info;
    int studentID;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int phone;
    int end;



while (info.end != -1) {
students = students + 1;
printf("Enter student information (ID, day, month, year, phone)\n");
printf("Enter -1 following the phone number to end the process to continue enter 0\n");
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &info.studentID, &info.day, &info.month, &info.year, &info.phone, &info.end);
}
if (info.end = -1){
printf("You entered %d student(s)\n", students);
}
//Student Search
printf("Please enter the student ID of the student your looking for\n.");
scanf("%d", info.studentID);
printf(" DOB: %d %d %d, Phone: %d", info.month, info.day, info.year, info.phone);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

info.end is not initialized before while (info.end != -1). Initiliaze all your variable (studentID...) and structure.

if (info.end = -1) is an assignment !

Use : if (info.end == -1)  I prefer to use if (-1 == info.end)  (if you had use : only = instead of == you would have get an error). (Yoda trick ^^)

And you have to use an array of struct in order to save every student (because you are continuously erasing the previous student information).

It's your homework, I won't do the work for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave most of the coding to you, as this is homework, but here is what you need to change to get this to work.

First of all, if you want to store multiple students info is going to need to be an array

```
static int MAX_STUDENTS = 50;
struct infoStruct info[MAX_STUDENTS];
```

and then you scan each student into a seperate part of the struct

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &info[students-1].studentID, &info[students-1].day, &info[students-1].month, &info[students-1].year, &info[students-1].phone, &info[students-1].end);
```

then you need to ensure that the end condition is checked properly (check the latest info[x].end)
It would also be wise to check you still have some room in the array before trying to add more.

with those done you are storing the students correctly.

as for searching, you need to scan the id to search into a seperate int.
then loop through the array (info[x]) and search each element's studentID against the search ID. When you have a match, print it out.

**Edit:**
     its also worth considering storing the phone number as a "string" rather than an int, alot of phone numbers start with "0", but an int would remove the 0.
(so the phone number 012345, would become, 12345)

Comment: About your edit : If he just want to display the number he can use (example) printf("%08u\n",info.phone); But I agree... using an unsigned int here is not really a good idea...

Comment: @Joze fair point print-formatting would fix it for you with a normal number. I'd say the string is more flexible, as you could store other characters (eg. "AreaCode-PhoneNumber"), but your solution would work fine for a simple case, like the OP's

Comment: @Daboyzuk I changed my program slightly by adding an array, but I'm still not sure how I'm supposed to search through it. Can you throw me a bone here give me a little more to work with. I've been working on this program for a couple days now trying to figure it out on my own, but I can't seem to figure this one out. As you can tell I'm quite new to programming. EDIT: I should also let you know that all my classes are online so getting ahold of my professor for help is a bit of a challenge, so I turn to you guys.

Comment: @user2172993 You have to use an array of struct (as shown in Daboyzuk message...)

Comment: @user2172993. Your search should be something like this.   `int sIndex=0;  while(sIndex < students) { if (info[sIndex].studentID == searchID){break;}  sIndex= sIndex +1;}`   when the loop ends... If sIndex is equal to students, the ID isn't in the array... If sIndex is less than students, it has found it.  You can then print info[sIndex]. This was typed from my mobile so excuse any typos!